Non-empty iterable type
In typescript it's straighforward to create a generic type for a non-empty array:
type NonEmptyArray<T> = [T, ...T[]];

How would this look if I wanted to abstract to a non-empty iterable? As far as I know there are only spread operators for array and object types. I don't know of any way in typescript to construct an iterable with explicit members set.

Is it even worth representing a non-empty iterable? The only thing you can do with one is try to consume it.  I can see some use-case of doing the opposite and having a type of a non-consumable iterable (exhausted or closed) which might help, since it's a signal that you shouldn't interact with it. But I'm not sure how "this iterable can be interacted with" is a useful type. Arrays are different, since you have other modes of interaction with those.

See Type Iterator result to a tuple and microsoft/TypeScript#42033 — Provide a way to type a fix-length tuple-like generator/iterator

Yeah, this is a missing feature, described at ms/TS#42033. Does that fully address the question? If so someone can write up an answer. If not, what's missing?
